# How to sale items that to be expire first using mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

Hi everyone I build a point of sale system in c# and now I want to sale items that will expire first. How can I  manage this by using MySQL query?

What I try:

```
query = Update Stock Set Quantity = Quantity - Sale_Qty Where Item_ID = 'some id' and expiry_date < Now()
```

But this not working I have a table of stock as following :

```
Stock_ID   |  Item_ID   |  Batch_No |   Quantity   |    Expiry_Date  | Sale_Price
   1       |     1      |  22042021 |      10      |    2021-04-22   |    150
   2       |     1      |  12052021 |       5      |    2021-05-12   |    155
   3       |     1      |  18032021 |       3      |    2021-03-18   |    142
```

I want to sale the item with id 1 from that row first which will expire first. Suppose I want to sale 10 quantity of item id 1 as of 3 qty of expiry date 2021-03-18 and 7 of expiry date 2021-04-22.
How to implement this using C# and MySQL? I'm newbie to C# and MySQL and learn a little about MySQL but I'm stuck here. Any answer will be appretiated.

Comment: "I want to sale 10 quantity of item id 1 as 3 minus from Stock_ID 3 and 7 from Stock_ID 1." Is very unclear please rephrase, thenI can give advice.

Comment: @S.JohnFagone Please check it again. Actually I want to sale items on FIFO order base on expiry date. I hope you get my question

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sale the items with closest expiry date first then you can simply order them by the date:

```cs
items.OrderBy(i => i.Expiry_Date);
```

If you want also to filter items by `Item_ID` you can use `Where` clause:

```cs
const int itemId = 1;
items.Where(i => i.ITEM_ID == itemId)
     .OrderBy(i => i.Expiry_Date)
     .ToList();
```

Comment: I want to sale items not order them

Comment: @Mr.AbdulRehman would you please explain to me what means "sale"? Do you want to call some method, like `Sale(itemId)` and provide the `itemId` to it?

Comment: as I mention in question I build a C# POS System I want to minus the item quantity on expiry date basis

Comment: I need a sql query to implement this

Comment: @Mr.AbdulRehman in order to use just SQL to mark items as expired I suggest you adding additional column like this: ` is_expired AS CASE WHEN Expiry_Date > GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`.

Comment: Additionally, you can create a TRIGGER(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the SQL table in order to check expiry dates on table updates and remove them.

Comment: @Mr.AbdulRehman there is no need to write the specific SQL queries for above. What I'm saying is that you can do the same with just `LINQ to Entities`. Sorry if I'm missing something.